# Android Preference Layout questions

Tags: android, android-layout, preferences

I would like to make something like this
http://goo.gl/km9T7Z

My codes looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


  <PreferenceCategory android:key="aaa"
        android:title="">
        <PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/bbb"
             android:key="ccc" />
        <PreferenceScreen android:title="@string/ddd"
             android:key="eee" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
  <PreferenceCategory android:key="fff"
        android:title="">
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="ggg"
            android:title="@string/hhh"
            android:defaultValue="true" 
            android:summary="" />
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="iii"
            android:title="@string/jjj"
            android:defaultValue="true" 
            android:summary="" />   
  </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

how can I make the background gray and something like the ">"?
thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

For each `Preference` you can set a custom layout using `android:layout="@layout/pref_item"`.

In that layout you can use a `LinearLayout` with a `TextView` and `ImageView` to get the desired look.

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. But I just wrote aaa.xml which just create a all RED background. Then I added to <PreferenceScreen
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout="@layout/aaa"> but nothing changed. I have no idea how to change background color

Comment: You must apply the layout to the sub items. I think the layout requires a `TextView` with `android:id="@android:id/text1"`. I haven't tried changing the parent layout before.

Comment: the issue still not fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can get that ">" symbol for **ListPreference**

***preference.xml***

```
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="@string/category1"

    >

    <ListPreference
        android:key="pref_key"
        android:title="@string/pref_title"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary"
        android:entries="@array/pref_list"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_values"
        android:defaultValue="50"
        />



</PreferenceCategory>
```

***string.xml***

these for showing a title and sub title for list of items

```
<string name="pref_tile">Preference Title</string>
<string name="pref_summary">Current pref value is:</string>
```

***arrays.xml***

names of item to display in list and respective values for each item

```
<string-array name="pref_list">
    <item>Item1</item>
    <item>Item2</item>
    <item>Item3</item>
    <item>Item4</item>

</string-array>
<string-array name="pref_values">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>

</string-array>
```